# Application works inside netbeans but distribution jar is not working

Tags: java, netbeans

I created an executable jar from netbeans.  Clicking on the jar did not work.  so I used the following at command line: java -jar "TestEye.jar" to see any issues.

This must be setup issue in netbeans.  If you have solution.  I would appreciated it.

```
Catched FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Users\Engineer101\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestEye\dist\lib\gluegen-rt-natives-windows-  
amd64.jar 
(The system cannot find the file specified), while TempJarCache.bootstrapNativeLib() of 
jar:file:/C:/Users/Engineer101/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestEye/dist/lib/gluegen-rt-natives 
windows-amd64.jar!/ (file:/C:/Users/Engineer101/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TestEye
/dist/lib/ + gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar)


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:442)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:59)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary
    (JNILibLoaderBase.java:90)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:328)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary
    (DynamicLibraryBundle.java:390)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.loadGlueGenRTImpl(Platform.java:251)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.access$000(Platform.java:57)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:186)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:183)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:183)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:82)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.Configuration.getMaxCompatibleGLProfile
    (Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.awt.WorldWindowGLCanvas.getCaps(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwind.awt.WorldWindowGLCanvas.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ApplicationTemplate$AppPanel.createWorld
    Window(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ApplicationTemplate$AppPanel.<init>
   (Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ApplicationTemplate$AppFrame.
    createAppPanel(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ApplicationTemplate$AppFrame.initialize
    (Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ApplicationTemplate$AppFrame.<init>
    (Unknown Source)
    at TestEye.TestEye$AppFrame.<init>(TestEye.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance
    (Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ApplicationTemplate.start
    (Unknown Source)
    at TestEye.TestEye.main(TestEye.java:209)
```

Comment: Make sure you have all the dependent jars available via -cp or -classpath argument.

Comment: Looks more like you're not including the native resources you need to run the program

Answer (score 0):

Double check that all the `jar` files that you use within your project are included in the `dist/lib` folder after your project `jar` file has been built. Take a look below at a `README.TXT` in the `dist` folder:

> When you build an Java application project that has a main class, the
>   IDE automatically copies all of the JAR files on the projects
>   classpath to your projects dist/lib folder. The IDE also adds each of
>   the JAR files to the Class-Path element in the application JAR files
>   manifest file (MANIFEST.MF).
>
> To run the project from the command line, go to the dist folder and
>   type the following:
>
> java -jar [project-name].jar
>
> To distribute this project, zip up the dist folder (including the lib
>   folder) and distribute the ZIP file.
>
> Notes:
>
> - If two JAR files on the project classpath have the same name, only the first JAR file is copied to the lib folder.
> - Only JAR files are copied to the lib folder. If the classpath contains other types of files or folders, these files (folders) are
>     not copied.
> - If a library on the projects classpath also has a Class-Path element specified in the manifest,the content of the Class-Path element has to
>     be on the projects runtime path.
> - To set a main class in a standard Java project, right-click the project node in the Projects window and choose Properties. Then click
>     Run and enter the class name in the Main Class field. Alternatively,
>     you can manually type the class name in the manifest Main-Class
>     element.

Good luck!

Comment: inside the dist directory.  I have the lib directory and executable jar. I opened the jar file to see the manifest,that is inside the META-INF directory.  The MANIFEST.MF states  Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_25-b16 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/antlr.jar lib/aspectjrt.jar lib/gdal.jar lib/gluegen-r
 t.jar lib/jogl-all.jar lib/nddsjava.jar lib/nddsjavad.jar lib/rtiddsg
 en.jar lib/worldwind.jar lib/worldwindx.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: Testseye.TestEye

Comment: That's very strange, why then is your program trying to find the jar file here: `C:\Users\Engineer101\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestEye\dist\lib\gluegen-rt-natives-windows-  
amd64.jar`? Do you refer to this path anywhere in your program?